# How webmails work with Google cloud hosting? Also how can I setup newsletter solution with MailWizz WordPress plugin in GCH?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, newsletter, webmail, mass-emails

I have been building a WordPress website and I am using Google Cloud Hosting as my hosting solution. I am very new in using the Google cloud hosting and I found it's not easy to understand things as I'm even not anyone with IT skill but previously worked with Cpanel hosting several times.

I am trying to establish similarities between GCloud and CPanel hosting but still failing. Researching a lot and I have a way to setup GCloud in CPanel but not sure if it will work and I am not doing that.

However, I want to create and access webmails (eg. yourname@domainname.com) for my personal and business uses. I am aware that I can create them with Zoho or any other mail servers with some costs but I am looking for a single tap solution keeping everything in one place. Hence, I am preferring Google cloud itself.

I am going to use MailWizz for Newsletters which will be also hosted in my own storage/server. It's just that MailChimp gives us email server but we need our own for email list/templates and data. But how can do all these? Can I create and access all these in Google cloud hosting?

If there is anyone to give me a solution regarding all these considering the preferences (I am not likely to use any other email hosting) this will be awesome and help me to make a decision for my upcoming websites. Thanks in advance.

R. K. Mahin

Answer (score 0):

GCP by default does not allow outbound connections for the port 25. [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/)
However there other approaches to achieve this too:

- You got SendGrid, MailGun and Google Apps. They provide solutions which doesn't require SMTP access from a GCE instance.
- There is also an alpha feature you can try to request called Cloud Mail. You can request to get your project whitelisted through Google Cloud Support.

If you can configure MailWizz to use other port than 25, you wont get into any trouble. You can create your own instance groups with a MailWizz server and a Load Balancer. GCP even got a Marketplace where you can find a lot of solutions to work with Wordpress and automatically create your own environment.

---